# In string theory, does each string interact with all the other strings in the universe, or just the closest ones?

Tags: string-theory, interactions

The question is likely to anger string theorists. But excuse me, I could not help but ask him.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/589542/2451